# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896 ?? error: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, npm-install

```
C:\>npm -v

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
6.14.8
```

//------------------------------------------

```
C:\>vue -v
```

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\maroc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli\bin\vue.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Comment: Could you adding more information about your version, OS, npm, node